# Pandas dataframe. Why data displayed is different from the stored one?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, statistics, mean

Applying "pivot_table" to df, I obtain a mean.

```
df_mean=df.pivot_table(index=['col_1']).sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
```

when I show the WIND column of the resulting dataframe

```
df_mean.WIND
Out[418]: 
col_1
P1              76.450000
P2              75.200000
P3              83.680000
P4              84.221429
P5              67.875000
Name: WIND, dtype: float64
```

Why is different when I access directly to the element?

```
df_mean.WIND[0]
Out[419]: 76.44999999999999
```

I would like to round up this (1 decimal), and I hope to obtain 76.5...

I have been looking for an answer, maybe is related to this?:

```
import statistics
df_calculo = pd.DataFrame({"A":[80.8,76.3,78.6,77.1,69.4,67.7,72.4,89.3]})
df_calculo.dtypes 
uu=statistics.mean(df_calculo["A"])
print(uu)#Is EXACT

uu2=df_calculo["A"].mean()
uu2#Is NOT exact
```

Which result in:

```
uu= 76.45
uu2= 76.44999999999999
```

Comment: I'm assuming `df_mean.WIND` is really `df_mean.VIENTO` and that all the occurrences of both are the same?

Comment: I have rewritten it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default display precision is 6 decimal places in Pandas. It's simply display rounding. The actual value is calculated using `np.mean()` as the default `agg_function`. So it is related to the type of mean used here.

[Pandas Docs on options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html): See "display.precision"

> Floating point output precision in terms of number of places after the decimal, for regular formatting as well as scientific notation. Similar to numpy’s precision print option

And [Docs on pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html): See "agg_function"

Comment: Ok, but although it is not the main question (is in the context I want an exact mean), why uu is exact and uu2 not?. If I wanted to finally get 76.45, I can either: change to type "decimal" before executing mean (), or it seems as if statistics.mean doesn't need previous decimal conversion to get an exact result.

Comment: Correct. Those are your options if you must have exact results. Either change the agg_function or change the input